# Java enum gives exception

Tags: java, exception, enums

I have enum `DebugMode` in a separate file `DebugMode.java`.

```
package core;
public enum DebugMode {
    Disabled, Console, Dialog, All
}
```

Then I have a class `Debug` in `Debug.java`.

```
package core;

public class Debug {
    private static DebugMode debug = DebugMode.All;
    public static void Message(String str) {
        //some unrelated stuff
    }
}
```

But for some reason it gives me error to this string:

```
private static DebugMode debug = DebugMode.All;
```

The error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - class DebugMode is public, should be declared in a file named DebugMode.java
    at core.DebugMode.<clinit>(Debug.java:6)
    ... 3 more
Java Result: 1
```

I just don't understand what's the problem... can someone help me figure it out?

Comment: The error seems to contradict the very first line of your question. Are you sure the enum is present in a separate file? If not, remove the public keyword.

Comment: Yes, I am absolutely sure. That's why I can't figure out why it doesn't work... I am using NetBeans if that's important.

Comment: Are you sure that you used the `enum` in the source? The error is saying that it is a `class`

Comment: Then add an import statement for the enum in the `Debug.java`.

Comment: search for the `type` `DebugMode`, your IDE might show you two results, if then delete the one you don't need, otherwise try to clean all an re build.

Comment: Check for spaces or similar in the file name

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I tried removing the file (again, btw), then closing IDE, then adding the file again and cupying contents inside, then "clean & build" and now it magically works. I guess I stumbled upon some bug in IDE...